# Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS No Internet connection

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

my ubuntu server is no longer accessible to the internet. during boot it will say

```
waiting for network configuration
```

then

```
waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration
```

then it just skips it and my server is not accessible remotely.

This just happened today, it was working just fine the other day and I don't recall messing with any settings.

I tried a different cable but that didn't help, the network card should be fine, it is a solid orange (which means its connected @ 1Gbps) and the switch I'm using is fine as the devices connected to it work.

I'm at a lost at what is the problem, any suggestions will be welcomed

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i unplugged the Ethernet cable and my ethernet socket was still a solid orange so i unplugged it from the surge protector and rebooted and it now works, not sure what happened but it working, wondering if my network adapter is going out, I'll keep it under check